# Calling methods on child components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to bypass React's `render()` for some deeper components that are drawing to Canvas, but I still want to use React to pass props, etc.  The problem I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to call methods on children like this.

What I have is basically:

```
<canvasRenderer state="active" mode={42}>
  <itemFoo fill="red" stroke="black" />
  <itemBar fill="blue" stroke="black" />
</canvasRenderer>
```

Then, within `canvasRenderer` I want to do:

```
constructor() {
  requestAnimationFrame(this.drawFrame);
}

drawFrame = () => {
  React.Children.forEach(children, (child) => {
    child.drawFrame(); // does not exist
  });
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: what is `child.drawFrame()`? have you tried calling it on `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: @goldylucks -- Within `itemFoo`, `itemBar` it's drawing code.  The problem is that in the loop `child` is some kind of React container object and not a reference to the actual element, so `drawFrame` doesn't exist.  it doesn't matter when it's called.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to call a method on the DOM element itself, use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

```
class Child extends React.component {

  drawFrame () {
    console.log('look ma, a child method!')
  }

  render () {
    <div ref={ el => this.el = el }>Some child content</div>
  }

}

class Parent extends React.component {
  componentDidMount () {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.drawFrame);
  }

  drawFrame = () => {
    React.Children.forEach((child) => {
      child.el.drawFrame(); // does not exist
    });
  }
}
```